# my htaccess for the sub domain is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a subdomain **imonline** on the domain *[www.techchef.co](http://techchef.co)*

I have already created subdomain in cpanel which is pointing to this folder. so the url should be [imonline.techchef.co](http://imonline.techchef.co)

i have tried wordpress provided .htacess for sub domain mentioned below but does not works, i have also tried some other configs too but it does not work even too.

**Please guide me what i am missing in .htacess file**

My Current htacess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**before that i was writing below one**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://imonline.techchef.co/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /imonline/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Sooo... where do you mention that subdomain of yours?

Comment: here is sub domain http://imonline.techchef.co

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I simply don't see where your attempt to redirect that subdomain is written in your .htaccess.

Comment: @Derija93 actually this is what i get from wordpress site http://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-subdomain-rewrite-rule before that i was writing another rule which i just mention in my edited question

Answer (score 2):

Regarding our little comment conversation:

## The mistakes

You lost me.

There are a lot of things wrong with your *.htaccess*. But I don't blame you. I believe everybody had a hard time getting along with mod_rewrite in the beginning... I even struggle sometimes even today. ;)

1. You have too many `[L]` flags. What do you think they do? The *L* stands for *last*. `[L]` terminates the routing routine. All subsequent directives are ignored.
2. You don't use a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.tld$` followed by an appropriate `RewriteRule`.
3. Your previous attempt would redirect **every** request to the subdomain and simply end there due to the `[L]` flag.
4. Even worse, you've used a `[R=301]` (moved **permanently**) during testing!! If any of your visitors visited your website in the meanwhile, their experience of your website may be broken forever! That is until they clean their browser cache.
5. `RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]` should redirect everything within the `wp-admin` directory to the `wp-admin/index.php` file, which isn't necessarily what you want. `wp-admin/edit/article` would also be routed to `wp-admin/`.

That about sums up all your mistakes I've noticed. Now let's go about redirecting your subdomain... I haven't tested this since my machine currently isn't set up for testing, so you might have to do some debugging. Actually you're likely to have to do some debugging.

## The solution - possibly

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect the subdomain to a directory.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imonline\.techchef\.co$ [NC] # NC = no case
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://techchef.co/imonline/$1 [L]

# Do not redirect actually existing files and directories. Optional?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

# Redirect everything to index.php, your last RewriteRule of your current .htaccess
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

The last `RewriteRule` depends on your CMS. I have little experience with WordPress, so I cannot tell. You may find respective information online.

As a matter of fact, a quick google search would have yielded the correct .htaccess. There are multiple templates for different scenarios [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess). Scroll down a bit to find one for subdomains.

I hope you could at least learn something... :P